# Confusion about UIButton's titleLabel and imageView property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, frame

I'v got two questions:

- Why the `button.titleLabel.center` equals `button.titleLabel.origin`,and
- Why the `imageView.frame` is nil?

  ```
      UIButton*button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      button.frame=CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 100);
      button.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
      [button setTitle:@"\U0000e602" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      button.font=iconfont;
      [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pig.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [self.view addSubview:button];

       NSLog(@"button.titleLabel.frame%@",NSStringFromCGRect(button.titleLabel.frame));

       NSLog(@"button.frame%@",NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
       NSLog(@"button.titleLabel.origin%@\nbutton.titleLabel.center%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(button.titleLabel.frame.origin),NSStringFromCGPoint(button.titleLabel.center));
       NSLog(@"button.imageView.frame%@",NSStringFromCGRect(button.imageView.frame));
  ```

And the results flows:

```
2015-09-08 13:27:43.507 IconFontTest[3458:152384] button.titleLabel.frame{{100, 50}, {0, 0}}
2015-09-08 13:27:43.508 IconFontTest[3458:152384] button.frame{{100, 200}, {200, 100}}
2015-09-08 13:27:43.508 IconFontTest[3458:152384] button.titleLabel.origin{100, 50}
button.titleLabel.center{100, 50}
2015-09-08 13:27:43.509 IconFontTest[3458:152384] button.imageView.frame{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since you are new, you should probably check out this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views are not rendered immediately as you set them. You need to wait for the next drawing update before logging their frame properties.

Have a look at The View Drawing Cycle section from the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/) on UIView. It is mentioned here:

> **For views that contain custom content using UIKit or Core Graphics,
>   the system calls the view’s drawRect: method**. Your implementation of
>   this method is responsible for drawing the view’s content into the
>   current graphics context, which is set up by the system automatically
>   prior to calling this method. This creates a static visual
>   representation of your view’s content that can then be displayed on
>   the screen.
>
> When the actual content of your view changes, it is your
>   responsibility to notify the system that your view needs to be
>   redrawn. You do this by calling your view’s setNeedsDisplay or
>   setNeedsDisplayInRect: method of the view. These methods let the
>   system know that it should update the view during the next drawing
>   cycle. **Because it waits until the next drawing cycle to update the
>   view**, you can call these methods on multiple views to update them at
>   the same time.

You should call the `setNeedsDisplay` method just before the log methods:

```
[button setNeedsDisplay];

//Log methods after the above line
```

Alternatively, you can try calling the log methods after a delay of, say 0.2 seconds to wait for the next drawing cycle to have completed.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"button.titleLabel.frame%@",NSStringFromCGRect(button.titleLabel.frame));
        NSLog(@"button.frame%@",NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
        NSLog(@"button.titleLabel.origin%@\nbutton.titleLabel.center%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(button.titleLabel.frame.origin),NSStringFromCGPoint(button.titleLabel.center));
        NSLog(@"button.imageView.frame%@",NSStringFromCGRect(button.imageView.frame));
    });
```

Comment: perfect,but why not the imageView.frame?it's still zero

Comment: Manish is right in his answer. The imageView property is only populated when you use `[button setImage];` I believe you cannot access the UIImageView in which a background image is rendered. You can only access the `currentBackgroundImage` as an UIImage

Answer (score -1):

`button.imageView.frame` is zero as you have used `setbackgroundImage:` method instead of `setImage:` method of UIButton.

Comment: The setImage: method is OK.